# Differentiating fields that didn't exist before schema change with Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to add a field to an elastic search schema.  I already have about a million records in the index which don't have the field and I need to be able to differentiate those from the ones that are added after the field is.  Using the modified date is the absolute last resort because I don't know when this will be turned on in production.

What I considered trying was the old records return something like

```
{
    myField: null
}
```

and the new ones would return

```
{
    myField: { }
}
```

But can't find a way to set the field on insert.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-exists-query.html

Comment: From that link, I ended up on [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html) which looks like it might help, depending on exactly how it works.  I tried running the exact commands from the page but I'm getting back the exact fields I'm sending.  It's not being modified by the mapping.